# Troubles with using transferFrom ethereum token (ERC827) function within web3

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

i have 2 already deployed contract:

**1. ERC 827 compatible token**

```
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value, bytes _data) public returns (bool) {
require(_to != address(this));

super.transferFrom(_from, _to, _value);

require(_to.call(_data));
return true;
```

}

**2. Test contract which upper method will call and pass some data via "_data" parameter.**

```
uint public data;

function setData(uint256 a) returns (bool) {
  
  data = a;
  Data(msg.sender, address(this), 10, a);
  return true;
```

}

Now i am trying to test the case where user1 calls transferFrom() which should call the Test contract 2.

```
var abi = require('ethereumjs-abi');

const expectSuccess = async (promise) => {
  if(isTestRPC()) {
  /* handle TestRPC */
  return (await promise)
 } else {
   /* handle everything else */
   let ret = await promise
   ret.receipt.status.should.be.equal("0x1")
   return ret
  }
}
it ('getData', async function() {

let token = await Token.at("token address");
let t = await Test.deployed();

let str = "getData(uint256)";
var encode = abi.simpleEncode(str,1)

 await expectSuccess(token.transferFrom(a2,t.address,web3.toBigNumber(10),encode));});
```

*Note: a2 address holds 10 tokens and was confirmed by previous tests.*

Running test above gives me an error:

> Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert. Other test done on the token contract (1) and test contract (2) are working OK.

Answer (score 1):

To use `transferFrom` you need first to execute method `approve` to actually allow address `_to` to spend `_from`'s account tokens, just like in ERC20 token.

### approve - ERC827

> Execute a function on `_spender` with the `_data` parameter, if the
>   function ends successfully allows `_spender` to withdraw from your
>   account multiple times, up to the `_value` amount. If this function is
>   called again it overwrites the current allowance with `_value`.

```
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _data) public returns (bool) {
    require(_spender != address(this));
    require(super.approve(_spender, _value));
    require(_spender.call(_data));
    return true;
}
```

---

Source: [original EIP: 827](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/827)

Comment: Thank you, for quick answer. I thought i do not need to approve it first. What am i actually trying to do is transfer tokens to a contract and do action upon. I would like to get rid of approving fist, so user would do everything in one step .... calling a function in a Test contract (with tokens). Something similar [link] (https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/223)

Comment: @user1756501 can you please elaborate what result you want to get? Because I don't understand the final goal. Do you even need `transferFrom` instead of `transfer`?